# Change background color for single word in TextEditor In SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I would like to change the background color in a TextEditor for a single word as shown in the image below
SwiftUI and Swift 5

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're using **SwiftUI 3 (iOS 15.0+, macOS 12.0+)** you can use `AttributedString` directly. However, if you plan to support older versions then you'll have to wrap a `UITextView` in a `UIViewRepresentable` and use `NSAttributedString`.

Edit: You can't use `AttributedString` with `TextEditor`, you can only use it with `Text`.

You'll have to use `UITextView`:

```
struct ColoredTextEditor: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    @State var coloredText: (String, UIColor?)
    init(text: Binding<String>) {
        self._text = text
        self.coloredText = (text.wrappedValue, nil)
    }
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let range = (text as NSString).range(of: text)
        let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: coloredText.0)
        if let color = coloredText.1 {
            mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range)
        }
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.attributedText = mutableAttributedString
        return textView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        let range = (text as NSString).range(of: text)
        let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: coloredText.0)
        if let color = coloredText.1 {
            mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range)
        }
        uiView.attributedText = mutableAttributedString
    }
    func color(text: String, color: UIColor) {
        coloredText = (text, color)
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @State var text = "Une phrase pour montrer"
    var body: some View {
        ColoredTextEditor(text: $text)
            .color(text: "Une", color: .purple)
    }
```

Comment: My application is on macOs for the latest version

Comment: You should be okay using AttributedString

Comment: Do you have an example of use with a TextEditor?